# Is there any good way to avoid mixing Exceptions and Error codes?

Tags: exception, design-patterns, error-handling, architecture, error-code

I've read a couple of articles and StackOverflow questions, however, I still have doubts when it comes to a real example.

I have a method Sync() that updates my entities from a remote data source. I don't expect any errors apart from bad connectivity (this is a mobile app). I have a tool that helps me to detect if the connectivity is bad in advance - in that case, I want to address that fact to the user. So how should I design my Sync() method?

**1. Throw exception**

```
if (!Connectivity.IsConnected)
{
    throw new BadConnectivityException();
}
```

Well, this is not truly an exceptional situation so it contradicts the general idea of using those.

**2. Return the error code (make hybrid)**

```
if (!Connectivity.IsConnected)
{
    return Error.BadConnectivity; // return false;
}
```

I'm not happy either... Let's say, I can treat all other errors as exceptional (server is not reachable, timeout happened, etc.). So I would end up handling both exceptions and error codes in the calling code.

**3. Move out?**
Potentially, I can check connectivity before calling the method which is not perfect because I would need to remember to do that in other places

```
if (Connectivity.IsConnected)
{
    await Sync();
}
```

Additionally, I can guard the Sync() method itself and duplicate the check inside. This time I can throw an exception with no doubts because I followed the principle "reduce the probability of exception to a minimum"

```
if (!Connectivity.IsConnected)
{
    throw new BadConnectivityException();
}
```

The drawbacks are obvious, though.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

A few things here. Largely I recommend using platform best practices and use cases (e.g. If there are already established practices for this scenario for your target platform, leverage those). Generally, if there is a way to detect device state, I recommend doing it automatically to help avoid these types of questions. It partly depends on what you have available in the application/platform.

TLDR: Avoid being in a situation that requires a decision between error codes and exceptions (find a way to do neither).

Hooking into a separate mechanism that detects connectivity state would enable the user to be notified and your connectivity-dependent code to behave accordingly.

You can also consider providing a sync result. If the device is not connected, the sync would fail. Provide the sync failure result rather than a connectivity exception.

Handle the changing connectivity state elsewhere. For example, consider notifying subscribers of connectivity change.

The subsequent code uses Java syntax but similar concepts can apply to other languages.

Define an interface or delegate that represents the connectivity change. For example:

```java
    public interface ConnectivityChangeListener {
        void onConnectivityChanged(boolean isConnected);
    }
```

Create a class that notifies subscribers of connectivity changes and provides methods to subscribe and unsubscribe from connectivity changes. Here's an example implementation:

```java
    public class ConnectivityNotifier {
        private List<ConnectivityChangeListener> subscribers = new ArrayList<>();
    
        public void subscribe(ConnectivityChangeListener listener) {
            subscribers.add(listener);
        }
    
        public void unsubscribe(ConnectivityChangeListener listener) {
            subscribers.remove(listener);
        }
    
        // Notify subscribers of change
        private void notifyConnectivityChange(boolean isConnected) {
            for (ConnectivityChangeListener listener : subscribers) {
                listener.onConnectivityChanged(isConnected);
            }
        }
    }
```

Create an instance of the ConnectivityNotifier and subscribe to connectivity changes:

```java
    ConnectivityNotifier connectivityNotifier = new ConnectivityNotifier();
    connectivityNotifier.subscribe(new ConnectivityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectivityChanged(boolean isConnected) {
            // Handle the connectivity change event here
            if (isConnected) {
                // Device is connected
                // Perform necessary actions
            } else {
                // Device is not connected
                // Display appropriate message or take actions
            }
        }
    });
```

Have a class to handle monitoring connectivity changes and notifying subscribers. Depending on the connectivity tool available, this code could automatically detect when connectivity changes. The class would monitor connectivity status and trigger notification on connectivity status change. I recommend using platform framework/tools for monitoring connectivity status. Here is a very bare example method just to complete the pattern:

```java
    void monitorConnectivity() {
        // Check connectivity status (using platform frameworks/tools).
        // I'm using a boolean here just for simplicity/brevity.
        boolean isConnected = Connectivity.IsConnected;
    
        // Update the connectivity status in the notifier.
        connectivityNotifier.notifyConnectivityChange(isConnected);
    }
```

Consider maintaining an instance of the ConnectivityNotifier in a more central area of the application that can be injected into subscribers.

By implementing this pattern, you can have multiple subscribers that are interested in device connectivity changes. Whenever the connectivity status changes, the ConnectivityNotifier will notify all the subscribers, and they can handle the event as needed.

Depending on your connectivity tool, you may be able to be notified of changing connectivity state and automatically notify subscribers of the changed state.

If none of this is possible and you must decide between error code, exception, or both: Don't use both. Device connectivity is a mobile application issue, not just a Sync method issue. Have a strategy applicable to the application.

If the device isn't connected, have a strategy for dealing with that appropriately across the application such as leveraging local storage first, then leverage sync as connection is established to reach eventual consistency. These would be 2 separate areas within the application. Background syncing could be appropriate. Simply don't sync until connection is established.

Remember to consider other factors, such as the overall architecture of your application, the expected frequency of bad connectivity, the impact on user experience, and the impact to data consistency before, during and after syncing.

Comment: Again, why are spamming my answers with this?

Comment: You're writing answers that are in form and content very like unto those easily generated by AIs, given the right prompts. Perhaps they were trained on your writings and that's the simple explanation why you both structure your answers the same way. Only you know whether you've been dishonest.

Comment: I use a similar format when presenting my answers to make it easier for people to understand while offering alternatives/options. This also allows me to better offer support as necessary as people go through them. What you are doing by flagging all of my answers as AI-generated is creating unnecessary noise and compromises the perceived legitimacy of my answers that can actually help people.